# Array value not working with preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

Why my code doesnt work? There is only one change between these examples.
I think maybe problem in $anchor type?

This code doesnt work:

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_name', 'db_pass'); 
mysql_select_db('db_name'); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_description");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 

$anchor = strval($row['description']); //Only this string changed!

    $anchor = preg_replace(
        '@\\<a\\b[^\\>]*\\>(.*?)\\<\\/a\\b[^\\>]*\\>@',
        '\\1',
        $anchor
    );

echo $anchor;

}


mysql_close($db);
?>
```

But this code works, i changed only one string here:

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_name', 'db_pass'); 
mysql_select_db('db_name'); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_description");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 

$anchor = 'Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a> Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>'; //Only this string changed!

    $anchor = preg_replace(
        '@\\<a\\b[^\\>]*\\>(.*?)\\<\\/a\\b[^\\>]*\\>@',
        '\\1',
        $anchor
    );

echo $anchor;

}
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: What is the point of the where clause here? And why did you tag this with sql server, it is pretty clear you are using mysql. The real issue though is that "doesn't work" is useless because it doesn't tell anybody what is wrong.

Comment: `var_dump($row)`

Comment: `var_dump($row)`: http://prntscr.com/jx6iw2

Comment: mysql_* functions were removed in PHP 7.  Your code will not work on a modern PHP installation

Comment: I use php 5.6 for this project

Comment: You still need to update your code to not use mysql_* because it's deprecated in 5.6.  They don't work properly with modern versions of mysql and haven't been maintained for years.  That's why they've been removed in php 7.  At the very least you should switch to mysqli

Comment: Ok, i ll switch to mysqli, thank you! Any ideas about my question?

Answer (score 0):

So.. I solved my problem.
Just replace

```
&quot; to "
&gt; to >
&lt; to <
```

.

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_name', 'db_pass'); 
mysql_select_db('db_name'); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_description");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 

$anchor = strval($row['description']); //Only this string changed!

// ADD THESE STRINGS START
$anchor = str_replace("&lt;","<",str_replace("&gt;",">",$anchor));
$anchor = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $anchor);
// ADD THESE STRINGS STOP

    $anchor = preg_replace(
        '@\\<a\\b[^\\>]*\\>(.*?)\\<\\/a\\b[^\\>]*\\>@',
        '\\1',
        $anchor
    );

echo $anchor;

}

mysql_close($db);
?>
```